# How to list some files, in a specific range

Tags: ls

I would like to list multiple files in a range. My files structure is PR181111???.s01 or PR189999???.s01 so the variable I have to use are 1111 and 9999.
This can be an operation to do several times a day with new files, hence is not a single-time listing.

In a script I tried to use (just an example)

```
ls *[0987-0991]*.s01
```

my output

```
PR180985026.s01  PR180987023.s01  PR180991022.s01
PR180987021.s01  PR180987025.s01  PR180991024.s01
```

Could someone explain me why I get the first file (PR180985026.s01)?

The first file is outside the range I specified, therefore I am doing something wrong.

Comment: That's not how `[...]` brackets work - they are sets (or collation sequences) of single characters

Comment: So how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> I try to list only file in range PR180987???.s01-PR180991???.s01

That can be done with for instance:

```
ls PR18{0987,0988,0989,0990,0991}???.s01
ls PR18[09]{87,88,89,90,91}???.s01
ls PR18[09]{87-91}???.s01
```

Comment: if I have more files in the range is not very useful....

Comment: @esse_emme your fault not mine. If you do not specify you do not get the answer you want. Then again: { and } are for ranges Feel free to adjust my answer to fit within what you want. The chars in between { } are also best done within a script with a for next loop. Saves typing.

Comment: I try to list files in ranges. The could be between PR181111???.s01 and PR189999???.s01. I I start typing all of them one life is not enough...

Comment: @esse_emme correct but again that is NOT what you asked. You asked about " between  0987 and 0991".

Comment: OK, but for testing I start using a limited range, otherwise....